# Remove embedded MongoDB document using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

so I got this embedded structure which looks something like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("529246fe6803fa2f1c16b7a7"),
    "title" : "presentation 0",
    "description" : "It's an awesome presentation about presentations, dawg!",
    "timestamp" : " 20:32:03",
    "slides" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("529246fe6803fa2f1c16b7a8"),
            "elements" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("529246fe6803fa2f1c16b7a9"),
                    ...
                },
                ...
       },
       ...
}
```

Where my root elements are presentations.

Now I want to be able to remove slides and elements using their ids.

I use

```
$result = $collection->update(
        array('_id' => $presentationId),
        array('$pull' => array('slides' => array('_id' => $slideId))
        ));
```

to remove slides, which works.

I tried

```
$result = $collection->update(
        array('_id' => $presentationId),
        array('$pull' => array('slides.elements' => array('_id' => $elementId))
        ));
```

to remove elements, but that didn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull a slide from presentation your syntax should be

```
db.coll.update({_id:presId},{$pull:{"slides._id": slidesId}}
```

To pull an element from a slide you need to match appropriate slide and use positional operator:

```
db.coll.update({ "_id": presId, "slides._id":slidesId},
{$pull: {"slides.$.elements":{"_id":elementId"}}})
```

I would test the second one - some operations on embedded arrays within arrays are not allowed.

Comment: thanks! 
in PHP it's db.coll.update({ _id: presId, "slides._id":slidesId},
{$pull: {"slides.$.elements":{"slides.elements._id":elementId"}}})

Comment: Isn't that what I said? :)

Comment: oh sorry, I meant in PHP it's db.coll.update({ _id: presId, "slides._id":slidesId}, {$pull: {"slides.$.elements":{"_id":elementId"}}})

Comment: oh doh, of course you're right - I forgot I was already including the first part of the field on the left side... I will edit to fix it.